# Need coldfusion version of php's sha1 and mb_convert_encoding

Tags: php, coldfusion, sha1, mb-convert-encoding

Does anyone know the coldfusion equivelent for this php code?

```
    $calcedVerify = sha1(mb_convert_encoding($pop, "UTF-8"));

    $calcedVerify = strtoupper(substr($calcedVerify,0,8));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfset calcedVerify = Hash(pop ,"SHA-1", "UTF-8")>
<cfset calcedVerify = Left(calcedVerify, 8)>
```

Note: The hexadecimal hash returned is already in uppercase.

`SHA-1` should be available in Standard Edition according to [Adobe ColdFusion 9 Web Application Construction Kit](http://books.google.ca/books?id=rI0OZhmcuc0C&lpg=PT259&ots=ilNlUgAxSs&dq=coldfusion%20hash%20sha%20sha-1&pg=PT259#v=onepage&q=coldfusion%20hash%20sha%20sha-1&f=false) even though the [hash() doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c52.html) said otherwise

`substr()` ~= `Mid()` but CF index starts from 1 instead of 0.

`strtoupper()` == `ucase()`

`mb_convert_encoding()` ~= `CharsetDecode()`